# here I am unable to display the data that got from json parsing?

Tags: ios, web-services, swift3

I get the following data using json parsing but I am unable to display it on the navigation bar title,pricelabel and textview which I had placed in storyboard. How to place an image from group of images also into it. Can anybody help me ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationbar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPricelbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionlbl: UITextView!

    var productName :String?
    var productprice :String?
    var productdescription :String?
    var thumbnailimageArray = [String]()
    var imageArray = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cjpberBhKa?indent=2"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
//        let imgURL = NSURL(string:imageArray[0])
//        if imgURL != nil {
//            let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
//            self.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
//        }
        self.navigationbar.topItem?.title = productName
        productDescriptionlbl.text = productdescription
        productPricelbl.text = productprice

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func arrowmarkButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail")!)
                if let detailsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? NSArray {
                        if let detailDict = detailsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                            if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "productName") {
                                self.productName = name as? String
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail1"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage1 as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail2"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail3"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail4"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail5"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail6"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail7"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail8"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail9"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail10"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let image1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image1"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image1 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image2 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image2"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image2 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image3 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image3"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image3 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image4 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image4"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image4 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image5 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image5"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image5 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image6 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image6"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image6 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image7 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image7"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image7 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image8 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image8"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image8 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image9 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image9"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image9 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image10 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image10"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image10 as! String)
                            }
                            if let price = detailDict.value(forKey: "productPrice") {
                                self.productprice = price as? String
                            }
                            if let description = detailDict.value(forKey: "productDes") {
                                self.productdescription = description as? String
                                print(self.productdescription)
                            }
                        }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `.value(forKey`. And anyway, you're using Swift, not Objective-C, so you should use Swift's array and dictionary instead of NSArray and NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is that you are updating UI elements in background thread. If you want to update UI element first come in main thread then update UI elements.

Try this way now

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationbar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPricelbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionlbl: UITextView!

    var productName :String?
    var productprice :String?
    var productdescription :String?
    var thumbnailimageArray = [String]()
    var imageArray = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cjpberBhKa?indent=2"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
//        let imgURL = NSURL(string:imageArray[0])
//        if imgURL != nil {
//            let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
//            self.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
//        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func arrowmarkButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail")!)
                if let detailsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? NSArray {
                        if let detailDict = detailsArray[0] as? NSDictionary {
                            if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "productName") {
                                self.productName = name as? String
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail1"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage1 as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail2"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail3"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail4"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail5"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail6"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail7"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail8"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail9"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let thumbnailimage = detailDict.value(forKey: "thumnail10"){
                                self.thumbnailimageArray.append(thumbnailimage as! String)
                            }
                            if let image1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image1"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image1 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image2 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image2"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image2 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image3 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image3"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image3 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image4 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image4"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image4 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image5 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image5"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image5 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image6 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image6"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image6 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image7 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image7"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image7 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image8 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image8"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image8 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image9 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image9"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image9 as! String)
                            }
                            if let image10 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image10"){
                                self.imageArray.append(image10 as! String)
                            }
                            if let price = detailDict.value(forKey: "productPrice") {
                                self.productprice = price as? String
                            }
                            if let description = detailDict.value(forKey: "productDes") {
                                self.productdescription = description as? String
                                print(self.productdescription)
                            }
                        }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                 self.navigationbar.topItem?.title = self.productName
                 self.productDescriptionlbl.text = self.productdescription
                 self.productPricelbl.text = self.productprice
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you bro and I asked another one also how to pass only one image from a group of images

Comment: on which condition you want to place one image from group of images
and in your code snippet you didn't show where your want to place image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you re setting data to the navigation title before having received it from the network.

Try doing what you did in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationbar.topItem?.title = productName
```

but instead do that inside the completion handler. Also try debugging the data inside the completion handler to make sure you're actually receiving something.

The rest of the question is a little hard to understand, please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

To change the navigation bar title, try using `navigationItem.title = productName`.
For the rest, you need to call `productDescriptionlbl.text = productdescription` and `productPricelbl.text = productprice` after your `downloadJsonWithURL()` not just in `viewDidLoad`